# Change parameter values in ALM test plan using OTA

Tags: qtp, hp-uft, alm, hp-quality-center

Is there any way to use OTA to manipulate test plans in ALM?

For example, I have 350 test plans in ALM and I want to change parameter settings for each of them. It is silly to do it manually.

Update 1:

After doing research about OTA for many hours, here are what I got now:

By using codes below, I can go to a test plan and get its name, but still don't know how to get a full list of BPComponents in it...

```
set tdc = createobject("TDApiOle80.TDConnection")
tdc.InitConnectionEx "http://URL:8080/qcbin"
tdc.Login "Username","Password"
tdc.Connect "Domain","Project"

If tdc.Connected = true Then
    print "Connect successful!!!"
End If

Set TreeMgr = tdc.TreeManager
    Set SubjRoot = TreeMgr.NodeByPath("Subject\")
    Set TestFact = tdc.TestFactory
    Set SubjectNodeList = SubjRoot.FindChildren("", False, "")

 For Each oSubjectNode In SubjectNodeList
        'Print out the subject path
        'Print oSubjectNode.Path

        'Does this have any tests?
        Set TestFilter = TestFact.Filter
        TestFilter.Filter("TS_SUBJECT") = Chr(34) & oSubjectNode.Path & Chr(34)
        Set TestList = TestFact.NewList(TestFilter.Text)
        For Each oTest In TestList
            print oTest.Name
'=============get stuck here========================
                Set Components=oTest.BPComponent
                Set Component=Components.Item(1)
'=============trying to get components list==========
            Next

Next
```

[This post](http://community.hpe.com/t5/Quality-Center-Practitioners/QC10-OTA-load-run-time-parameters-in-Test-Plan-Please-help/td-p/5966789) seems provide a way to edit parameter values. But the issue is that the `Test` object doesn't support `Test.Load` method.

Update 2:

After more researching, I don't think we can do it through UFT/QTP. The reason is that: according to OTA official guide (link [here](http://alm-help.saas.hp.com/en/12.50/api_refs/ota/webframe.html)), we need to "cast the `Test` to `BusinessProcess`". Seems this can't be done in VBScript because VBS doesn't have something like `Dim As` or `CType`.

Next step: maybe I can try to do it on test plan level but not component level?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by myself.

Here are details:

First, by using OTA, we can't touch Component level; but we can manipulate test plan/lab level. Which means if we want to change parameter values using OTA, we need to create a global parameter at test plan level and change it.

Below are some sample codes:

```
'=====================Initial ALM Connection=================='
set tdc = createobject("TDApiOle80.TDConnection")
tdc.InitConnectionEx "ALM URL"
tdc.Login "UserName","Password"
tdc.Connect "Domain","Project"

If tdc.Connected = true Then
    print "Connect successful!!!"
else
    'do something'
End If
'=====================Initial ALM Connection=================='



'====================Get all test plans under a folder========================
    Set treeMng = tdc.TreeManager
    Set sourceFolder = treeMng.NodeByPath("Subject\Path")
    Set testF = sourceFolder.TestFactory
    ' Find the test ID.
     Set aFilter = testF.Filter
     Set TestList = testF.NewList("")
     For each test in TestList
        print test.Name
        '=========Can search a specific test plan here'
        If test.Name = "TestCaseName" Then
            set TestObj = test
        End If
     Next
'====================Get all test plans under a folder========================


'====================Modify test plan name===================='
'After get a specific TestObj
TestObj.Name = "New Name"
TestObj.Post
'====================Modify test plan name===================='


'====================Change parameter value=====================
Set para = TestObj.TestParameterFactory
Set paraList = Para.NewList("")
For each a in paraList
    If a.Name = "Para1" Then
        a.Name = "Modified1"
        a.DefaultValue = "ValueModified1"
        a.Post
        a.UnLockObject
    End If

    If a.Name = "para2" Then
        a.Name = "Modified2"
        a.DefaultValue = "ValueModified2"
        a.Post
        a.UnLockObject
    End If
Next
'====================Change parameter value=====================



'====================Search a specific test plan, copy and paste==============
Set treeMng = tdc.TreeManager
Set sourceFolder = treeMng.NodeByPath("Subject\Path")
Set testF = sourceFolder.TestFactory
' Find the test ID.
Set aFilter = testF.Filter
Set TestList = testF.NewList("")
TestName = """Test_Case_Name"""
aFilter.Filter("TS_NAME") = TestName
Set TestsList = aFilter.NewList()
Set Test = TestsList.Item(1)
print Test.id
Set iscp = testF
clipboard = iscp.CopyToClipBoard(Test.ID, 0, "")
Set destFolder = treeMng.NodeByPath("Subject\Path")
Set testF = destFolder.TestFactory
Set iscp = testF
iscp.PasteFromClipBoard clipboard,destFolder.NodeID,0,1
destFolder.Refresh
'====================Search a specific test plan, copy and paste==============
```